# External USB disk won't mount

Tags: mac, usb, external-hard-drive

I have an external LaCie HDD that connects via USB to my computer. It was working fine, but now it won't appear on the Desktop, in the Finder, or in Disk Utility.

I know it's connected, because System Profiler shows it as connected on the USB page, but I can't find any other sign of it. (Also, it's not available as `/dev/disk1`; the only things in `/dev` that start with `disk` are `disk0`, `disk0s1`, and `disk0s2`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's not showing up in Disk Utility, you have a problem. I suggest trying different USB cables, power supplies, etc.

You should also try looking on the [LaCie support website](http://www.lacie.com/us/support/index.htm). If you don't find a pre-baked answer there, you can file a support ticket and they'll get back to you soon. In my experience they have been fairly helpful.

Comment: But see, I feel like the problem *isn't* the USB cable, since I can see the drive in System Profiler.

Comment: It may be that somehow it's able to recognize the USB device, but not communicate with the drive. In any case, I'd try LaCie Support.

Comment: I think that it must be a physical problem. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out the power cable was faulty.